# Sorting included headers in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is there a function, extension, or add-in that will allow me to select a block of `#include` directives and sort them lexicographically based on filename? (NB I'm using Visual Studio 2012 RC)

Comment: No, that would be the kind of feature that just breaks programs.  The exact order of #includes is very often important.

Comment: I'm keeping standard library and platform #includes separate from my own project includes. I just want to sort my own - and I make sure they are order independent.

Comment: Does anybody know about this simple extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few minutes of searching I found this FREE addon: http://www.menees.com/.

I has a lot of functionality and one of it is Sort of text which can be used for sorting included headers.

Version for Visual Studio 2012:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/42de112b-3ecf-4a9e-94f0-2b5efb053aa6

For other versions (VC++6.0/20032005/2008/2010) see website (free download).

Answer (score 0):

[Menees VS Tools 2019 referred above](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2019&ssr=false#review-details) It's a good extension but kind of bloated (mix of diverse functionality). I've found every "individual component" of it as a single extension.

As for Header file sort, I would recommend this one [IncludeToolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wumpf.IncludeToolbox)